# Silverlight 4 - Display Images

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am using the following tutorial to implement a gile upload system : [file-upload-in-silverlight-a-simple-solution](http://gregdoesit.com/2009/10/file-upload-in-silverlight-a-simple-solution/). I can get the images to upload into my Projects.Web folder. However, in my silverlight project I cannot get them to display. This is what I am using to display the image.

```
<Image Source="..//Theme/Theme2.jpg"/>
```

However, that fails to display anything although I am sure the path is correct.

Comment: Is the image located on your hard disk, or is it part of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in the ClientBin folder you can use: `/images/theme/theme2.jpg`

If the image is in the root of the web you can use: `http://localhost:57097/images/theme/theme2.jpg`

Comment: By doing so, I get the followin error:
The file '../images/theme/theme2.jpg' is not part of the project or its build action...

Comment: Sorry, when outside of the ClientBin you will have to prefix the image with the entire path. See my edit. If you do not want that you will have to store them in the ClientBin or set the urls programatically; that way you could resolve the server name and port dynamically.

Comment: Aha, I see, And how is it possible to combine something like this: <Image Source="http://localhost:1234/" + "{Binding Current.FilePath}"/>

Comment: You could use a Value converter.